# Desktop Screen video quality problems .mov to mp4 ( via quickTimerPlayer )

Tags: html, video, converters, mp4, mov

For my WebService i need to record my desktop screen (+ audio). For personal use apples build in QuickTimerPlayer record function works totally fine. 
Unfortunately it saves the records as .mov files.

Dueto the fact that i need to embadded the video in an HTML document via:

```
  `<video width="" height="" controls>
         <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>`
```

EDIT:

i tried a software called "Wondershare Video Converter Ultimate". when i convert the .mov file into .mp4 with this software the output file (mp4) is of great quality and the browser notices it as valid .mp4 source. but this software costs 100$ there got to be a way to convert .mov into .mp4 of same quality without spending 100$

I need those screen videos as MP4. I tried some converting software but the mp4 output were of such a bad quality that you could not even read whats written on my screen.

Any clew how i could capture my screen (videos) so that i can use the html5 video source mp4 tags?

Answer (score 0):

mp4 is a superset of mov. Just renaming it will probably work. You MAY need to `qt-faststart` the file.

Comment: renaming mov into .mp4 did not work. the browser says: "no video with supported format and no MIME type found...

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a way  to display high quality screen records in html 5.

what i tried:
- convert high quality mov into mp4

problem occured:
- mp4 was of very poor quality

solution now:
- i converter .mov into .ogg 
-> the .ogg allowed me to keep the video quality almost 1:1 but convert it to a html5/browser readable format

```
<source src="videos/test4.ogg" type="video/ogg">
```